# DES enctypted file gives different results

Tags: linux, openssl, des, tripledes

I have a file which I am trying to decrypt using OpenSSL from bash:

```
openssl des-ede3 -in test.bin -out test.txt -md md5 -k 'HELLO'
```

Each time I run this command I get different results in test.txt, Why is that? Shouldn't the result be the same given the same key?

Answer (score 2):

When not given a salt value, it seems to generate a random value on each run.

With a hexadecimal salt value specified like so `-S cafed00d`, I get the same result on subsequent runs.

Reference: `man enc`.

Side note: I find no reference of `-md md5` in man pages. This appears to be unused?